# Set up https server on google-app-engine express . . how to get certificates

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, google-app-engine, https

We try to move node.js restful api to GCP. MySql is running normally as SQL instance. I have successfully deployed node.js app as App Engine service. I can see it works ok as GET request is comming through ok, with status 200. However, I am unable to connect to MySQL from this app, as I can see that when I try to init mysql-password-store (I am using passwordless.js library for authentication), I am not able to come through. Error is this:

```
Error: Server does not support secure connection at /workspace/node_modules/passwordless/lib/passwordless/passwordless.js:445:10
```

I believe the reason is in fact that I am running http server, as opposed to https server in my express (node.js) app.
I was able to get to work custom domain, thinking this will solve SSL issues, however the problem I believe lies in somewhere between eypress and mysql.

Can someone please explain how can I run https server on AppEngine. I don't understand how or where to get certificates to pass into part for creating https server:

```
 const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.PATH_PRIVKEY),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.PATH_FULLCHAIN)
};
https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  winston.info(
    `********** App running on port: ${port} - https *** in mode:${process.env.NODE_ENV} on host:${process.env.NODE_HOST} ********** `
  );

});
```

I am able to run app as http server from localhost and connect to GCP SQL MySql instance. . .

Comment: Hi @Gregor Sotošek, could you please check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance) and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you @MarcAnthonyB - - I believe running https server on GCE is not the right way.  Somehow I have problem accessing mysql-express-store.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone hits similar problem, I'll briefly decribe how we got it solved. We moved node.js (REST api with express) to Cloud Run service, and hit same problem . . Routes that were calling stored procedures in our DB (MySql instance in Cloud SQL) could not communicate until we did following:

1. Cloud Run - Service - Service Details - Edit and deploy - Connection - - here the connection to db instance needs to be inserted into Cloud SQL Connection
2. In our node app . . connection to mysql (via knex) should be made with socketPath (unix way) . . instead of classic IP,PORT way. We are still using public IP at MySql.
3. in node.js (express) we set up http server and not https. Seems to me that gs takes care of the cerificates.

Maybe someone find this helpful.